Stubbing requests in ActiveJob for jobs enqueued by other jobs using Rails, Rspec, and WebMock
I'm writing tests for a Job in my Rails app. When the Job receives over 500 messages, it enqueues other jobs to handle the messages. When it receives less than 500 messages, it handles the messages itself.
My tests that test jobs handling less than 500 messages work as expected, where the stubbed request returns the batch_response body.
RSpec.describe SendCloudMessengerNotificationJob, type: :job do
  # ...code and variables
  describe 'batch send with less than 500 tokens' do
    before do
     stub_request(:post, /fcm.googleapis.com/).to_return(
        status: 200,
        body: batch_response.to_json,
        headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
       )

      described_class.perform_now(data)
    end

    it 'sends a message to the devices' do
      expect(a_request(:post, /fcm.googleapis.com/)).to have_been_made.once
    end

    it 'creates a Firebase::Notification for each failed record' do
      expect(Firebase::Notification.where(failed: true).count).to eq(50)
    end

    it 'creates a Firebase::Notification for each successful record' do
      expect(Firebase::Notification.where(delivered: true).count).to eq(50)
    end
  end
end

In the tests where more than 500 messages are submitted, the stub is ignored in the jobs that get enqueued by the job logic, causing the tests to fail.
I've worked around it by only testing that the sub-jobs get enqueued the expected number of times, and stubbing a method in the job class responsible for parsing the response. However, I don't think it's an optimal solution.
RSpec.describe SendCloudMessengerNotificationJob, type: :job do
  describe 'batch send with more than 500 tokens' do
    # ...code and variables
    before do  
      # This job enqueues other jobs to handle the dispatch of messages when more than
      # 500 messages are present. This causes an issue in the tests as the requests in
      # the jobs enqueued in the test do not get stubbed properly. Thus, we stub the JSON
      # response method, as the other tests are covering that we have sufficient coverage
      # of the jobs that recieve 500 messages or less.
      allow_any_instance_of(SendCloudMessengerNotificationJob).to receive(:json_response).and_return(
        {
          responses: Array.new(SendCloudMessengerNotificationJob::SEND_LIMIT) do
            { success: true }
          end
        }
      )

      described_class.perform_now(data)
    end

    it 'enqueues multiple jobs to send the messages in batches of 500' do
      expect(SendCloudMessengerNotificationJob).to have_been_enqueued.twice
    end

    it 'doesn\'t call the submit the messages to firebase cloud messaging' do
      expect(a_request(:post, /fcm.googleapis.com/)).to_not have_been_made
    end
  end
end

Is there a way to stub the requests for these nested jobs that are getting enqueued? I would have expected WebMock to handle them all at the network level, however, it seems that's not what's happening.
